# Set default value of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, default-value

Is there a summarised way to write this code

```
if(y) {x=y;} else {x="default"}
```

I tried

```
$x=$y||"default"
```

but it fails.

Comment: `$x = $y ? $y : 'default';`

Comment: I think `$x=$y?:'default';` will do it for PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the PHP ternary operator, like so:

```
$x = $y ?: "default";
```

If you are using PHP < 5.3, you'll need to use the full ternary form like so:

```
$x = $y ? $y : "default";
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this be in a function? You can do:

```
function foo($bar = "default")
{
    if(x==y)
    {
        $bar="something";
    }
    return $bar; //will return "default" if x!=y
}
```

Or do you just mean that you want to write something like:

```
$x == $y ? $bar = "something" : $bar = "default";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = isset($y) && $y ? $y : 'default';
```

So what you're doing here, is checking to see if the variable $y (whatever that may be in your code) is set, and if so, checking to see if it holds a true value (anything that isn't empty, null, or 0). When that passes the checks, then $x is assigned to the value of $y, if not, then $x is assigned to the string 'default'.

This is called a short-hand conditional expression:

$x = <if this is true> ? <then set it to this> : <else, set it to this>;

can also be used to output something with echo:

echo <if this is true> ? <output this> : <else, output this>;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way would be using ternary operator:

```
$x = $y ? $y : "default";
```